# Stripe 3d-secure verification in react ionic ios-app issue

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, stripe-payments, ionic4

we have created a react ionic app and deployed it to the app store. We are using stripe as payment solution in the app in the ionic app.

**Problem:**
We have a problem with the 3d-secure verification for one of four bank's. The 3d-secure iframe won't load in the stripe popup.

**This is the bank's response about our problem:**
We prevent identification to open in an iframe in any non-https domain (parent). In these cases, our content security policy (CSP) might prevent the Nordea identification to open in the web view.

How do solve this ssl-problem? The request is done by the stripe-library.

Answer (score 1):

If the bank has a Content Security Policy that prevents their authentication flow from opening in an iframe with a non-HTTPS parent you may need to handle payments on an HTTPS page hosted on your web server, or [handle 3D Secure manually and redirect to an HTTPS page hosted on your server](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure#controlling-when-to-present-the-3d-secure-flow).

[You can enable HTTPS in Ionic](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/1686), but there are [several major issues](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3305) when you do.